# What happens with data persisted in memory when using autoscaling on task nodes?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-emr, autoscaling

I'm using AWS EMR with Spark/Scala. Say I have a large DataFrame that I choose to persist. the persist() method may be lazy but let's say I activate it right after, with a .show()

```
df.persist()
df.show()
```

My understanding is it stores it in memory, so it's quicker to use next time. Let's say autoscaling kicks in and scales half of my task nodes back.

If I do a `df.select`, after the task nodes are terminated, will it still work? Or is that block lost from the terminated nodes? Or does it get persisted to the core nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AWS EMR, only core nodes will store the data blocks. Task nodes only help with scaling up the compute power by reading data from core nodes.

Ideally each executor will store few partitions of your dataset in memory, when you lose an executor, missing partition will be recomputed based on the reassignment of partitions on to the existing executors/resources.

Comment: +1 ... and this can happen on-prem too if your over-share executors are preempted by FairScheduler for example, so its not only cloud/autoscaling specific situation.